# T-test across two regressions (seemingly unrelated)

Tags: r, regression, t-test, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I want to compare across two regressions if the coefficients are equivalent using a t-test, how could I approach this and is there a function in R, which does this for seemingly unrelated regressions? The linearhypothesis function only supports chi square and f-tests.

Comment: Could you state the specific null and alternative hypotheses?  Your reference to "coefficients are equivalent" is highly ambiguous because it leaves undetermined how many coefficients and what you mean by equivalent.

Comment: @whuber so I have two regressions, where for the first I regress some portfolio 1 on the market return and some smb factor, for the second its some portfolio 2 on the market return and some hml factor. I want to test now if the coefficients on the market return are the same

Comment: That's fine: you seem to have answered your own question by mentioning the t-test.  What else do you need to know?  (I am suspicious of the hint that the regressors "smb" and "hml" are different in the two situations, which raises a concern that the two coefficients can't even be compared, but presumably you have thought that through and determined that this is not a problem.)

Comment: @whuber My question is how should I implement this in R as I run seemingly unrelated regressions with the systemfit package. The t.test function does not really work in this case. Is there an implemented fucntion or how do I need to proceed for the test?